# ngCordova Push Plugin in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova, ngcordova, apache-cordova

I installed Push Plugin as Custom plugin from the github URL in my Visual Studio project (Tools For Apache Cordova).

However, i am not able to get it working as when i try to reference $cordovaPush in my app, it thows an error:

this is how my angular.run function looks like:

```
angular.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $cordovaPush) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleLightContent();
        }

        var androidConfig = {
            "senderID": "replace_with_sender_id",
        };
        debugger
        $cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function (result) {
            // Success
            debugger
        }, function (err) {
            // Error
            debugger
        })

    });

})
```

Error in the console: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]`

It looks like it does not understand what `$cordovaPush` is.

Comment: angular.run is not a function

Comment: @Vanojx1 - angular.run is a valid function. You can think of it as analogous to a "main" block in other languages. You can read a little about it at: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module.

Comment: @Asdfg To use [$cordovaPush](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/) from ngCordova you'll need the Push plugin (which it sounds like you have installed) and you'll also need to download and reference ngCordova .JS files which define that $cordovaPush service in Angular. Have you downloaded .js files from ngcordova.com and referenced them in your app?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio's Cordova Tools. I am not sure what am i supposed to do after installing the plugin. I am aware of the normal development using Atom and installing it manually but trying my hands on visual studio 2015 now. so far it is very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the install guide on their site? http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/

If you add ngcordova via bower on the command line (first navigate to the root of the www/ folder), and then reopen your project in VS, the packages should be there (or you can search for them and manually add them to your project.)

Then you can make the code changes (adding script tags and adding ngcordova as a dependency).